# Is the double integral equal to the area?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to compute the double integral $\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}\int_x^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}} 2\sin(y^2)dydx$.

I drawed the region $0\leq x\leq \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ and $x\leq y\leq \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$. This is a triangle with height and base equal to $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$, right?

The double integral is equal to the are of the triangle, or not?

So, is the double integral equal to $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{\pi}{4}$ ?

Comment: Think what would happen if the integrand would be another function. What if the integrand is zero?

Comment: Ah... Can we no use the graph of the region to compute the double integral? @jinawee

Comment: Isn't the integrand zero at $y=0$ and $y=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ ? @jinawee

Comment: If you assume that the area of a region is unique and since an integral depends on the integrand (the integral of x is different than the integral of an exponential or of  the number seven, right?) your assumption must be wrong. The answer is that if you integrate the constant one, you get the area (length in one dimension, volume in three).

Comment: An analogy: Do you also think that $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ is always equal to $b-a$ (the length of the interval)?

Comment: I think of it as a signed volume. I think of a "single" integral as signed area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that the double integral over that triangle can be written as iterated integrals in two ways. 
\begin{align*}
\int_{x=0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}\left(\int_{y=x}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}} 2\sin(y^2)dy\right)dx
&=\int_{y=0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}\left(\int_{x=0}^{y} 2\sin(y^2)dx\right)dy\\
&=\int_{y=0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}2\sin(y^2)\left(\int_{x=0}^{y} dx\right)dy\\
&=\int_{y=0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}2y\sin(y^2)dy.
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

P.S. The final result is different from what you have found. It is not the area of the triangle.

Comment: Do we change the variable $u=y^2$ so that computing the integral is easier? Or is there an other way maybe by the area?

Comment: @Mary Star Yes, the change of variable is fine.

Comment: Then we get $\int_{u=0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(u)du$, which is easy to compute, right?

Comment: The result is then $1$, or not?

Comment: But according to Wolfram the result must be $\frac{1}{2}$, or not?

Comment: @Mary Star Yes, the result is $1$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(int(2sin(y%5E2),y%3Dx..sqrt(Pi%2F2)),x%3D0..sqrt(Pi%2F2));

Answer (score 2):

You have a heap of sand on a triangular lot. The height of the heap at the point $(x,y)$ is defined to be $2\sin(y^2)$.  The integral you are told to compute is the **volume** of that heap.

Answer (score 1):

The triangular region you found is called the domain of integration. The integrand function is a two variable function: $f(x,y)=2\sin(y^2)$. The double integral of a two-variable function shows the volume under the graph (surface) of the two-variable function in the given domain of integration. (Similarly, the integral of a one-variable function shows the area under the graph of the one-variable function in the given domain (interval) of integration). One of the methods of calculation of a double integral is to change the order of integration. (See [here](http://mathinsight.org/double_integral_change_order_integration_examples) for examples). Hence you should apply this method for your double integral.